# why doesn't the cursor show up for resizing docked views?

Tags: c#, view

A strange thing started to happen with our application. The mouse cursor used to change when you hover over the border of a view so that you know you can start to drag and resize that view. Suddenly the cursor no longer shows up and it's difficult to resize the views because of this.

Update: It was found that this only happens after we open up another view. The views that are in a docked pane can be resized BUT the cursor doesn't show up. The cursor does show up until I open that one particular view I was talking about earlier AND if I undock the view from its docked pane.

Anybody have any ideas why this might happen? Has this ever happened to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out there was a "Mouse.OverrideCursor" variable that works globally for the application and it was set to override the cursor. Now this really means it is overridden and not changed when it would normally be changed like hovering over a horizontal or vertical resize border.

Solution: You have to set that global variable to null like this ...

Originally:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Now:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```